# generate index/position of string from a csv string in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, group-concat

I am in a need in **MySQL** to generating something from

```
"Java, MySQL, Python"
```

to

```
"1,2,3"
```

The idea is I have 3 string in the csv string and I need a sequence of integer from 1 to n (3).

The csv string is generated from `GROUP_CONCAT()` function of mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple `1,2,3`? or these values are indexes/identifiers of separate string values taken from another table?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE main SELECT "Java,MySQL,Python" txt, NULL idx;
> CREATE TABLE ref SELECT 1 id, 'Java' val UNION SELECT 2, 'MySQL' UNION SELECT 3, 'Python';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT main.txt, GROUP_CONCAT(ref.id)
> FROM main
> JOIN ref ON FIND_IN_SET(ref.val, main.txt)
> GROUP BY main.txt
> ```
>
> | txt | GROUP_CONCAT(ref.id) |
> | --- | --- |
> | Java,MySQL,Python | 1,2,3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e73b6bfdda7a038a1a4c047058c4260a)*

---

**UPDATE**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE main (txt TEXT, idx TEXT);
> INSERT INTO main (txt) VALUES 
> ('Java,MySQL,Python'),
> ('C++,Python,MySQL,PostgreSQL');
> SELECT * FROM main;
> ```
>
> | txt | idx |
> | --- | --- |
> | Java,MySQL,Python | *null* |
> | C++,Python,MySQL,PostgreSQL | *null* |

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ref (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, val VARCHAR(255));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ref (val)
> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(txt, ',', num), ',', -1)
> FROM main
> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION 
>              SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) nums;
>
> UPDATE main
>   JOIN ( SELECT main.txt, 
>                 GROUP_CONCAT(ref.id ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ref.val, main.txt)) idx
>          FROM main
>          JOIN ref ON FIND_IN_SET(ref.val, main.txt)
>          GROUP BY main.txt ) data USING (txt)
> SET main.idx = data.idx;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM ref;
> SELECT * FROM main;
> ```
>
> | id | val |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | C++ |
> | 2 | Java |
> | 3 | Python |
> | 4 | MySQL |
> | 5 | PostgreSQL |
>
> | txt | idx |
> | --- | --- |
> | Java,MySQL,Python | 2,4,3 |
> | C++,Python,MySQL,PostgreSQL | 1,3,4,5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=41e242421b7b4726bef0ec87ef14b726)*

You may alter ORDER BY clause in GROUP_CONCAT() if needed.

The subquery `num` must generate adjacent integers from 1 to a number not less than the amount of separate values in CSV. Alternatively you may use some service table with such list (created specially, or use, for example, `mysql.help_keyword`).

Both queries may be placed into one stored procedure.

Pay attention - there is **NO** space char between comma and CSV value. If present then this space will be treated as a part of the value (`'MySQL'` and `' MySQL'` are two different values).

Comment: Actually your `ref` table should be my output depending the `main` table. In your answer, you hardcoded the `ref` table which is not possible in my case. Actually I want to generate the position/index of each string. If the input string is `Java, MySQL` then output should be `1,2`. I hope i can make it clear. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to **create and fill** `ref` table based on `main` table data? Or you need simply generate new value which contains adjacent integers? Anycase provide **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: anyone is okay with my situation. MySQL 5.7.30

Comment: @sarwar026 Is there some upper limit for an amount of separate values per CSV? Alternatively - is stored procedure, not single query, safe for you?

Comment: I am doing this in a stored procedure, actually. upper limit will be not so much ... if you have a solution, please share. thanks in advance.

Comment: @sarwar026 Added.